# jni CallStaticLongMethod always return 0L

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a static method in a Java class called `getCurrValue()`

```
package com.my;
public class MyClass {
    public static long value = 5L;
    public static long getCurrValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

and I have a method in native c/c++ code called `useValue(JNIEnv* env)`.
When I try to use the Java static method `getCurrValue()` to get the `value` in native c/c++ code , I always get `0L` as result - why?

```
void useValue(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/my/MyClass");
    jlong result = -1L;
    jmethodID get_curr_value_method_id = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz,"getCurrValue","()J");
    result = env->CallStaticLongMethod(clazz,get_curr_value_method_id);
    // the result is 0L
}
```

Comment: Did you check for exceptions after the call?

Comment: @ EJP actually , I don't find any exceptions had been thrown.

Comment: You checked that how?

Comment: @EJP -,- I do this just like java , if there is none message be shown on the screen, I knew it don't have exceptions , Is this way right ?

Comment: @EJP My mistake , when I test the return value , I use the format "%ld" , but jlong is a long long type , when I change the format to "%lld" , evertything is ok . thanks anyway.

Comment: Check for exceptions with `ExceptionCheck` or `ExceptionOccurred`.  See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#exceptions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code in a native method and on my Nexus 9 with Android 6.0 and it's working perfectly.

```
jstring Java_it_stefanocappa_ndkexample_Example_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz ) {    
    jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, thiz);        
    jmethodID staticMethodId1;
    staticMethodId1 = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, clazz, "getCurrValue", "()J");
    jlong staticMethodResult2;
    staticMethodResult2 = (jlong) (*env)->CallStaticLongMethod(env, clazz, staticMethodId1);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI);
}
```

If you are not satisfied about my answer, please write and i'll post the entire fully-working example ;)

---

Update as suggested:

I updated a project on Github that i realized some months ago.

Repository: https://github.com/Ks89/NdkExample_AndroidStudio

Look "example.c" lines 155-166.

Obviously, in this example there are also other features.

Comment: My mistake , when I test the return value , I use the format "%ld" , but jlong is a long long type , when I change the format to "%lld" , evertything is ok . If you can post the entire fully-working example. and  It may help more people I think , Thanks .

Comment: If there is any chance of the Java-language method throwing an exception, the native code needs to check for exceptions before continuing. If an exception is thrown, the return value is undefined, and things may blow up strangely later on. Code intended for use as a correct example should be especially diligent.  See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#exceptions

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll update the example when I'll some free time.